# Trying to have the abilty to rate the app within the app

Tags: ios

I'm trying to have the ability of the app to rate it within the app by calling up the web browser. Right now I get a message saying cannot connect to app store
code

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=803063953"]];
```

Comment: Would recommend [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Can you show us how you're opening the url?